# iPhoneConnect: ## Unable to mount developer disk image, Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402652958

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading to macOS High Sierra, I'm getting this error when running `xcodebuild` from the terminal.

```
2017-09-26 10:11:03.990 xcodebuild[1333:141317]  iPhoneConnect: ## Unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402652958 "Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c26a0d DTDKCreateNSError + 113
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c27251 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 1135
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c681b7 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 782
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c68a6e -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 488
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000116b4c495 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 133
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ada60eb __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 806
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d447a2 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d3cf64 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d50110 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 599
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d478e0 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d3eb56 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d3e902 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff550001ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff54fffc4d start_wqthread + 13
), NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2)., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).}) {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c26a0d DTDKCreateNSError + 113
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c27251 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 1135
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c681b7 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 782
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116c68a6e -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 488
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000116b4c495 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 133
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ada60eb __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 806
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d447a2 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d3cf64 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d50110 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 599
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d478e0 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d3eb56 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff54d3e902 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff550001ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff54fffc4d start_wqthread + 13
);
}
```

Code builds and tests pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like running the tests from Xcode in all platforms "unlocks" the simulators, and the error no longer appears when running `xcodebuild` from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the error log clearly identifies the issue, which is a locked iOS device.  When you run the compile with the device active and unlocked, the error does not occur.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that error with locked devices. However, in this case, it was right after upgrading the operating system and the error was happening with the simulators. Once run the tests from Xcode, the simulators were "unlocked".

Answer (score 0):

My problem is this.
After searching a lot and not finding a solution, I happened to find it, well for my case.

But before I was intrigued by the publication of a single screen app and few components work, ie in the same environment and mobile and macOS a full app could not publish and the simple all right.

Well absordial but the simple lack of "/" at the end of "RemotePath" was my problem.

Error-> RemotePath = StartUp / Documents

OK-> RemotePath = StartUp / Documents /

I did not have any more problems.